# A reference manual for Web2Py

Tags: web2py, reference-manual

I've recently switched from PHP to Web2Py and was wondering if Web2Py has a manual like [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) does.
The [Web2Py book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/6) and the Alter Ego blog are very nice, but I am looking for a quick reference for the Classes and Methods available in Web2Py.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068466/sources-of-web2py-documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation page](http://web2py.com/examples/default/documentation) links to some resources, including the Epydoc-generated [source code documentation](http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/epydoc/index.html). You may also find it helfpul to explore the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/) directly.

Comment: Thank you @Anthony, the **epydoc** looks fairly good. 

Some of the best parts of the PHP manual come from the user-comments, perhaps we could build a crowd-sourced ref for Web2Py sometime :)